# Некорректно работает таймер внутри жизненного цикла компонента react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Component extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {date: new Date(), name: "Vladimir"};
}

    componentDidMount(){
    this.timerID = setInterval(
        () => this.tick(), 1000);

    setTimeout(
    this.setState({
        name: "Andrey"
    }), 10000);
}


    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
}

    tick(){
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
    });
}  

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, {this.state.name}</h1>
                <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Component />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Выводится Андрей сразу после рендеринга, как сделать так чтобы имя выводилось через 10 секунд, какой жизненный цикл использовать лучше?

Comment: Минус за плохое оформление.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы `setTimeout` выполнился `после` заданной задержки первым аргументом нужно передавать функцию, вы же ее сразу выполняете.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    name: "Andrey"
  });
}, 10000);
```